# C# Compile Fix visual studio

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compile a C# file but I'm getting the following errors

```
Error   CS0234  type name or namespace "ManagementClass" doesn't exist no namespace "System.Management" (you're without an assembly reference?) Program C:\Users\Desktop\Project\Program\system.cs  60  Active
Error   CS0234  type name or namespace "ManagementClass" doesn't exist no namespace "System.Management" (you're without an assembly reference?) Program C:\Users\Desktop\Project\Program\system.cs  60  Active
Error   CS0234  type name or namespace "ManagementObjectCollection" doesn't exist no namespace "System.Management" (you're without an assembly reference?)  Program C:\Users\Desktop\Project\Program\system.cs  61  Active
Error   CS0234  type name or namespace "ManagementBaseObject" doesn't exist no namespace "System.Management" (you're without an assembly reference?)    Program C:\Users\Desktop\Project\Program\system.cs  62  Active
Error   CS1579  the foreach instruction can't operate variablse of type 'ManagementObjectCollection' porque 'ManagementObjectCollection' doesn't contain a public instance to 'GetEnumerator'   Program C:\Users\Desktop\Project\Program\system.cs  62  Active
Error   CS0234  type name or namespace "ManagementClass" doesn't exist no namespace "System.Management" (you're without an assembly reference?) Program C:\Users\Desktop\Project\Program\system.cs  79  Active
Error   CS0234  type name or namespace "ManagementClass" doesn't exist no namespace "System.Management" (you're without an assembly reference?) Program C:\Users\Desktop\Project\Program\system.cs  79  Active
Error   CS0234  type name or namespace "ManagementObjectCollection" doesn't exist no namespace "System.Management" (you're without an assembly reference?)  Program C:\Users\Desktop\Project\Program\system.cs  80  Active
Error   CS0234  type name or namespace "ManagementBaseObject" doesn't exist no namespace "System.Management" (you're without an assembly reference?)    Program C:\Users\Desktop\Project\Program\system.cs  81  Active
Error   CS1579  the foreach instruction can't operate variablse of type 'ManagementObjectCollection' porque 'ManagementObjectCollection' doesn't contain a public instance to 'GetEnumerator'   Program C:\Users\Desktop\Project\Program\system.cs  81  Active
```

This errors report to lines 60-81 of the code bellow

```
        System.Management.ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);
        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
        foreach (System.Management.ManagementBaseObject mo in moc)
        {
            if (mo[wmiMustBeTrue].ToString() != "True") continue;
            if (result != "") continue;
            try
            {
                result = mo[wmiProperty].ToString();
                break;
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
        return result;
    }
    private static string Identifier(string wmiClass, string wmiProperty)
    {
        string result = "";
        System.Management.ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass(wmiClass);
        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
        foreach (System.Management.ManagementBaseObject mo in moc)
```

I don't see what may be the cause and what changes do I need to do

EDIT:

I was trying to install now "Install-Package System.Management -Version 6.0.0" from https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/  but I'm getting the error

```
Install-Package : Unable to install package 'System.Management 6.0.0'. You are trying to install this package in a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain
no assembly or content file references that support this structure. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package System.Management
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to install System.Management from nuget.

Follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio) guide, just replace `Newtonsoft.Json` with `System.Management`.

Comment: Either this or the solution needs to be cleaned/rebuilt

Comment: @POBIX I have followed the site and after that (and maybe I'm doing it wrong) but I have replaced  System.Management.ManagementClass (example) by Newtonsoft.Json.ManagementClass and did this to the others System.Management. But doing this or leaving as it was its the same

Comment: @mi.tnd Which package did you install? I meant that you shouldn't change the code, but instead of searching for Newtonsoft.Json like the guide says, search for System.Management.

Comment: @POSIX Understood. Sorry for the confusion. I have edit the question as this box doesn't allow me to write everything here. The package is this but should I choose any other version? Because if the case I'm not finding it.

Comment: @mi.tnd You are using an extremely out of date version of .NET (from 2010!) Try installing a more recent version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I have tested bot on vs2017 and 2022 but I'm still getting the same errors. I will make some reviews on the code to see what can I change

Comment: @mi.tnd [Change your project's target framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2017#change-the-target-framework) to .NET Framework 4.5 or above.

Comment: @POBIX I have changed to .NET 4.8 and getting the same errors I will nedd to check the code again. Thank you for your help

Comment: @mi.tnd The code is definitely not the issue here, the original errors tell you that the System.Management package is missing, and the ones from the edit tell you that the package doesn't support your version of .NET. Try installing different versions of the package (looking at the version naming scheme, it looks like each version refers to a specific .net version, so you'd want 480 for 4.8), and if that fails google stuff related to nuget failing to install packages.

Comment: thank you I will do that. I will try others .NET versions as I only tried the most recent one